# Sorting a map on key of type XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Map<XMLGregorianCalender,Long>`. I want to sort the data by `DESCENDING XMLGregorianCalender` and put the data into another `TreeMap`.

I tried overriding implementing `Comparator` method, but failed.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Please show us the code you tried, hopefully we can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a `compare()` method, `XMLGregorianCalendar` does not implement `Comparable` so you cannot use the default sort methods.

You can do either one of these in order to be able to use `Collections.sort()`:

- Subclass `XMLGregorianCalendar` and implement `Comparable`
- Create your own `Comparator` for sorting your map using the builtin `XMLGregorianCalendar.compare()` method

Be aware that sorting a `Map` will involve using either `SortedMap` or `TreeMap` iirc.